# Calling Convention of exported methods in ntdll.dll

Tags: c, windows

I have some trouble to call an exported method from Ntdll.dll

In debug mode with VS2012 I do get:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved
>   across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a
>   function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer
>   declared with a different calling convention

This is the code I have used (x86 platform, Windows 7).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>

typedef NTSTATUS (* NTAPI  ZwClose)(HANDLE handle);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ZwClose close = (ZwClose) ::GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll"), "ZwClose");
    close(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);  // Error happens here
        return -1;
}
```

From what I have read it should work. I have also tried __cdecl and __fastcall as alternate calling conventions but nothing did work.

Comment: Why are you calling APIs not documented for use in user-mode? Make sure your customers understand that your program is not guaranteed to work on future versions of Windows.

Comment: ZwClose is documented http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but you are right that this was only an example of another method that I need to call which is indeed not documented at all.

Comment: If you look closely, that is kernel mode documentation, not user mode documentation.

Comment: Yes but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx explains how the methods of ntdll and ntoskrnl.exe are related. ... "However, a user-mode application might directly call an Nt or Zw routine to perform an operation that is not supported by the Win32 routines." ...

Comment: Whether something happens is different from whether it is supported. If you start calling unsupported functions, you need to make it clear to your customers, "This program does things that are known not to be supported. It may stop working at any time."

Comment: To make you and my customers sleep well at night I promise to use this undocumented stuff only for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a bad casting, it should be:

```
typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI* ZwClose)(HANDLE handle);
```

Your declaration made a pointer to function to be in C convention.
C calling convention is the same as STDCALL, except the stack is corrected by the caller.

```
;C
push arg1
call fun
add esp, 4 
...

; STDCALL

push arg1
call func
```

In disassembly You could see that after calling ZwClose, value of Esp is being checked.
As Your calling of ZwClose was in C convention, esp value was corrected by caller and
by the function itself which brings to error ofc.

```
000F14C4  mov         esi,esp  
000F14C6  push        0FFFFFFFFh  
000F14C8  call        dword ptr [close]  
000F14CB  add         esp,4  
000F14CE  cmp         esi,esp  
000F14D0  call        @ILT+380(__RTC_CheckEsp) (0F1181h) ; Run-Time Check Failure #0
```

Comment: Ahh thanks that did it. I wonder what my original declaration did then? Change the calling convention of the pointer?

Comment: Putting the calling convention at the wrong place without any compiler warning sounds like a bug to me.